# error: Package `libcanberra' not found in specified Vala API directories

Tags: programming, development, vala

When I try to compile a project with pkg [libcanberra](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=libcanberra/Canberra) using command [valac --pkg libcanberra *.vala
], I am getting below error,

> error: Package `libcanberra' not found in specified Vala API
>   directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories Compilation
>   failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Comment: Have you installed the development package libcanberra-dev?

Comment: Yes, I didn't install it. After installing works fine. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing libcanberra-dev package solved the issue.